# Ruby script cannot locate required gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to run a Ruby script that has worked fine in the past. I need to use the Mechanize gem, so at the top of the script, it says `require 'mechanize'`. However, when I try to run the script now, the Terminal output reads:

```
/Users/codebiker/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)
from /Users/codebiker/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from myscript.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

When I run `gem env`, as suggested here, I get:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/codebiker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/codebiker/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/codebiker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/codebiker/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/codebiker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
     - /Users/codebiker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :benchmark => false
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gemcutter.org"]
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
     - http://gemcutter.org
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/codebiker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
     - /Users/codebiker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin
     - /Users/codebiker/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /usr/texbin
     - /Users/codebiker/.rvm/bin
```

When I run `rvm get head`, I get:

```
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/codebiker/.rvm/
RVM PATH line found in /Users/codebiker/.bashrc /Users/codebiker/.zshrc.
RVM sourcing line found in /Users/codebiker/.bash_profile /Users/codebiker/.zprofile.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/codebiker/.rvm/ is complete.
```

When I run `which ruby`, I get:

`/Users/codebiker/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby`

And `ruby -v` gives me:

`ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`

Any advice, thoughts, or tips would be appreciated! I have no idea what's wrong here.

Comment: Possibly too obvious, the gem is installed right?

Comment: Type this is cmd `gem install mechanize`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gems must first be installed before you can `require` them in a script. To install a gem; first open a terminal window and then type:

`gem install GEM-NAME` or in your case: `gem install mechanize`

Comment: This completely fixed it -- thanks! However, I'm not sure why Mechanize wasn't there anymore. I've used the Mechanize gem in my scripts on my computer plenty of times before so I just assumed there was no need to install it again. Why would it suddenly disappear? Could this have to do with my recent Ruby 2.1 installation?

Comment: Yes that is exactly right. Each ruby installation will have an independent directory for gems. Glad I could help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

If you use [bundler](/questions/tagged/bundler), add into your [gemfile](/questions/tagged/gemfile) link to [mechanize](/questions/tagged/mechanize) gem:

```
gem 'mechanize'
```

Then issue bundle installation for your[rails](/questions/tagged/rails) or other project folder:

```
$ bundle install
```

Make sure that [mechanize](/questions/tagged/mechanize) gem is present in the [gemfile.lock](/questions/tagged/gemfile.lock) after the bundle installation.

Then even in case if you don't use bundler, make sure that bundle founds the gem:

```
$ bundle show mechanize
/path/to/mechanize/gem
```

Then if your app isn't the [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) app, just run your app with:

```
$ bundle exec ./your_app
```

Comment: Great response, thanks! I voted feed_me_code's answer as correct because this is just a script, not a full app, but I appreciate the advice. I am curious if you happen to have an idea of why the gem disappeared. (I would never uninstall it as I use it a lot.)

Comment: @CodeBiker If you use rvm, you can install it into other gemset. or if you've used the root installation, it could be treated as an other gemset also.