# Mechanize/Ruby: `require': cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, command-line, terminal, mechanize

I've been trying to run a ruby file from terminal using:

```
ruby file_cleanse_auto.rb
```

but I get an error from mechanize:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from file_cleanse_auto.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

In my ruby file I have:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'
```

I'm able to use mechanize without any errors with the Ruby shell (irb). It seems that it's only an issue when I'm trying to run ruby files from the command line.
The versions of ruby and mechanize I have installed are 2.0.0 and 2.7.5 respectively.
I've also tried adding mechanize to the Gemfile (with and without nokogiri). This is what it looks like now:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'mechanize'
```

After running:

```
bundle
```

I got:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Using mini_portile2 2.2.0
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using net-http-digest_auth 1.4.1
Using net-http-persistent 2.9.4
Using ntlm-http 0.1.1
Using webrobots 0.1.2
Using bundler 1.15.1
Using nokogiri 1.8.0
Using unf 0.1.4
Using mime-types 3.1
Using domain_name 0.5.20170404
Using http-cookie 1.0.3
Using mechanize 2.7.5
Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 14 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But I still get the same error when I try running the ruby file again. Does someone know how I could resolve this error? Thanks!

Comment: You can try `bundle exec ruby`

Comment: maybe `require 'rubygems'` at the top

Comment: I've tried both of those but when I type in bundle exec ruby, and press enter,  nothing happens. There's just the cursor on an empty line.

Comment: And adding require 'rubygems' and running the file still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after recently installing `ruby 2.4`.

You should try **`gem install mechanize`**

This is because each [ruby installation have an independent directory for gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149367/ruby-script-cannot-locate-required-gem). Hopefully that works.